# Why does reg.exe runs three processes when my Windows 8 starts up?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, regedit

Whenever I start up my PC (running Windows 8.1) I am able to see three windows of running `reg.exe` program for a flash of a second. Some times they are visible for a longer duration and that was when I was able to get the below screenshot.

[image]

From this [link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-edit-the-windows-registry-without-opening-regedit-exe) I gather that `reg.exe` is a command-line utility with same features as `regedit.exe`.

In my Task Manager's Startup tab I can see `Registry Console Tool` enabled with three entries.

[image]

How can I check why `reg.exe` starts up at boot time? Will disabling these processes will have adverse effects on my PC?

Comment: Are you able to disable it?  This normally happens when a malicious infection exists on your system.

Comment: Use AutoRuns to see more details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Answer (score 1):

### The manual way

To find out what they do, I recommend you take a look at the `Run`-location in the registry, located at:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

  or...
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

  or...
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

It's a bit strange that you have three startup items for reg.exe, so I'd check out the registry keys and see what parameters the instances for `reg.exe` have.

Comment: In both cases I could not find the entry for `reg.exe` in my registry.

Comment: @Naveen Sorry, I forgot another location! I updated my answer.

Comment: Searched your new location, but still could not find any mention.

Comment: @Naveen In that case, you should use AutoRuns per magicandre1981's comment, downloadable from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have that if you have some IBM software installed.
IBM Notes for example put on startup  3 registry key who looks like that:

HKLM:Run    !IBM Notes Browser Plugin IE Registration       REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\ProtocolDefaults" /v notes /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f

HKLM:Run    IBM NBP Disable IE Popup Blocker        REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" /v 1809 /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f

HKLM:Run    IBM NBP Disable IE Protected Mode       REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" /v 2500 /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f

Answer (score 0):

You can check what applications are launched at system startup/login with [Sysinternals Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

If you find out these `reg.exe` processes are not related to a software you specifically installed you should disable it with Sysinternals Autoruns.